# Populate Facebook Feed Dialog from SQL database

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, dialog, feed

is it possible to populate Facebooks Feed Dialog dynamically with PHP variables fetched from an SQL database in a safe way?

```
    ...
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with people.'
    };
    ...
```

I guess that for example:

```
    name: '<?php echo $name; ?>', etc..
```

should be possible..but what if the name contains an ' character? Same thing with the descrption since that will likely consist of different special chars that might break the javascript code.

How can i avoid this or is there a "pure" php based method to fill an Feed Dialog with database content as images, name, description and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to produce a javascript object, the easiest way is to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php), which will take care of all the escaping for you:

```
<?php
$fb_feed = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'method' => 'feed',
  ...
);
?>
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($fb_feed) ?>;
```

Note that if for some reason you don't want to produce your whole object like that, you can also use it with a single field:

```
var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      name: <?php echo json_encode($name) ?>,
      ...
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest escaping, but this is clearly the correct answer. +1

Comment: I see, easy as that! Thank you for your time.